# iOS 95% web-based app crashes when I add one more JS file

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

The app I'm developing is using Appcelerator, but only as a small wrapper around a WebView, where 95% of the action takes place. It's been working absolutely fine, until this morning when I added another JavaScript file to my web folder. The crash traces all look something like:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000000f594828

VM Regions Near 0xf594828:
TC malloc              000000000f486000-000000000f586000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> JS garbage collector   000000000f588000-000000000f5a4000 [  112K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
JS garbage collector   000000000f5a4000-000000000f5b8000 [   80K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
```

Is it really possible that I'm loading up "too much" JS? My app isn't *that* huge and complex, but given that the error is something to do with JS garbage collection I have to assume that something along these lines is happening.

I know this isn't much to go on, but any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing anything "interesting" or slightly away from "mundane" with the extra JS file?

Comment: No- I've actually tried completely emptying it out in the hope that it might make a difference, but no luck. However, if I take out the code that tries to *load* the file, it works fine. Insanity.

Answer (score 0):

One more JS file may not cause problems. I've been working on huges app using phoneGap and Sencha et it doesn't really matter how much js you put in.

Try to verify path to your libraries or files, invert them if necessary. Try also to have 777 acces to all folder and sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before. This may not be the issue, but how are you building your functions?

If you are building your functions like this: `function foo() {}` at some seemingly arbitrary point the app will crash once you add one more of these.

Instead use this form: `var foo = function() {}`

Using this format will allow you to have virtually unlimited functions. I know it sounds silly but it works.